# in this sql “replace into ..”, is atomic or not?

Tags: mysql

Does the sql "replace into .." is atomic?
this is the sql

```
"replace into A(id,name) values(1,'dd')";
```

and at the same time i use

```
select * from A
```

does the results change to 'null' or not, whatever in a very short time? (in normal situation)

Comment: _does the results change to 'null' or not_ What result?

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. 
If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided.

Comment: If you have another column, lets say `address` then yes, the `address` column would be set to NULL because REPLACE is an INSERT that checks for duplicate keys, and if it finds one, the old row is deleted and a new one INSERTED. So as you didnt provide a value for `address` it will be NULL in the new row

Answer (score 0):

For this type of question it is easy to code a schema.
Here we put a CHECK constraint so that the REPLACE INTO will fail. We see that the original row is neither deleted now modfied. We can conclude that the transaction is rolled back following the error.

> ```
> create table A (
> id int primary key,
> name varchar(10),
> constraint name_not_dd check (name <> 'dd'));
> insert into A values (1,'aa');
> select * from A;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> id | name
> -: | :---
>  1 | aa
> ```

> ```
> replace into A(id,name) values(1,'dd');
> ```
>
> ```
> Check constraint 'name_not_dd' is violated.
> ```

> ```
> select * from A;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name
> -: | :---
>  1 | aa
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65e8cbe63c49531df030d0b4bdc154e3)*